# TYPO3 is it possible to resize images automaticly after upload?

Tags: image, resize, resolution, typo3, autoresize

With the advent of super High Definition camera's I got the problem that my TYPO3 users are uploading a lot of impossible image resolutions into TYPO3 (like 6000 x 4000). Is it somehow possible to automaticly resize this to an accepting resolution? It would be nice when its possible with the TCA configuration but unfortunately there is only a `maxsize` config possible.

The images are attached to a lot of difference functionality (like page, page-content, extensions etcetera) so I need some kind of generally solution (I already know the possibilities with TypoScript/pibase and extbase).

Comment: Do you ask for image detection? Face detection? If the size is too big don't allow the user to upload. Problem solved.

Comment: @Chiyou why should I disallow this? It should be possible in a cms like TYPO3 to autoresize the images after upload. The maxsize suggestion is horrible and pure unnecessary restriction when the user doesnt know anything about image resolutions.

Comment: I dont see a reason for down voting my question..

Comment: I think your question is too localized. As I stated how is this autoresize working? Does it crop images?

Comment: @Chiyou: There is nothing "too localized" about the question. Actually I think it's a great question. Not putting the burden of resizing images on (computer illiterate) editors who might screw the image quality before it's uploaded while keeping down the server disk space taken by those images is completely reasonable and valid requirement.

Comment: @Cascaval: I can be wrong. Sorry for that. But I think the question is to vague. It's still a question of yes and no and doesn't really ask for an algorithm or something. It shouldn't belong here.

Comment: @Chiyou: I don't think the question is vague. Whether it belongs here or not is a different issue. It does ask for *configuration* and thus is about development. If we agree that only **programming** questions might be asked here, then in my opinion 90% of TYPO3 questions don't qualify (including those about Typoscrpt which is nothing but *configuration*).

Comment: @Chiyou: ...oh and all the questions purely about HTML or CSS wouldn't qualify either.

Comment: @cascaval: Anyway this place has many problem with closing question, etc. I think it's moderators problem, too. Look my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13060467/technical-difference-between-2400-and-0000/13060557#comment17739054_13060557.

Comment: @Chiyou: Well, the problem of the question you mentioned is that it deals with a non-existent problem. [One of the answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13060823/772810) sums it up very well. This question on the other hand deals with an exisitng problem that many TYPO3 admins/developers face and it does involve **coding** (setting `TCA` in my opinion qualifies as coding). However, I admit that sometimes there is a fine line between acceptable and not acceptable question and I did see questions being closed even though they were in my opinon valid.

Comment: @cascaval: That's not true. It's simply an ambigous description for the transition of a day to another. You need 2 VARIABLES to mathematically describe this transition. EXCUSE ME TIME IS IMPORTANT and although I'm new to date and calender programming I proposed my client a "military" time and he literally piss on me !???!?

Comment: @Chiyou: I'm sorry, I'm not gonna get involved here in the discussion about the other question. You got the answers there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Its possible. Try extension "image_autoresize"

http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/image_autoresize

Comment: Looks very promising. I will give it a try as well. Thanks!