# Difference between 24:00 and 00:00?

Tags: php, date

What is the difference between 24:00 clock and 00:00 clock. IMO 24:00 clock is the day before and 00:00 clock is the beginning of the new day. But I'm not really convinced and I'm new to date programming

Update: Here is what wikipedia article say about military time and style guide about how to deal with 24:00 and 00:00 confusion: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock#section_1.

Comment: Where did you get 24:00 from? After 23:59 it should be 00:00 in a 24h clock. Can you show a function that generates 24:00 or it is not related to any language?

Comment: It is useful to be able to show late-night appointments as 25:00 ~ 25:30 on calendars, though (and not let them fold over into the page for the next day) :-)

Comment: @Thilo: and 23:00-56:30 for multi day appointments or what? Sounds like a rather stupid idea in my eyes ;)

Comment: @hakre: I've never seen it used that way, and I guess that it isn't because a multi-day appointment spans multiple days anyway, whereas a 23:30 ~ 26:00 event arguably does not. And this notation is in actual use, in case you were wondering.

Comment: @Thilo: Well, arguably 23:30 - 26:00 spans across two days and therefore qualify as a multi-day appointment as multi starts at two.

Comment: A 23:30 ~ 26:00 scheduled server maintenance only spans two days if you fall asleep in the middle ;-)

Comment: The notation is in common use for late-night movie schedules at least in Japan: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090207184509AA5Ci56

Comment: Hours up to 27.00 or so is very common i East Asia, for opening hours of restaurant and bars, etc. It is actually quite convinient once you get used to it. (In Sweden, bus and train timetables often show time shortly after midnight at e.g. Saturday/Sunday as `Saturday 00.30`, for readability. That approach, on the other hand, can cause a lot of confusion, and also doesn't work well in programming...)

Comment: @Thilo I find that awful. These hours do not exist.

Comment: When developing an app, and letting people for example select times for the start and end of an event or booking on a certain date, it is far more sensible to use 24:00 to indicate the end of the day at midnight, as opposed to 23:59:59.9999. Hence the usage of 24:00 to differentiate from 0:00 (which is midnight but at the start of that same day). So it's not uncommon to see or use 24:00 in apps, while formally midnight is 0:00. Tbh this is far less confusing than the 12am/pm thing, which has no good way of differentiating start/end of day midnights.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After 23:59 comes 0:00, not 24:00
Please see the code below, in php, as you put the 'php' tag:

```
echo date('G:i:s', mktime(0,0,0)) . "\n" ;
echo date('G:i:s', mktime(0,0,0)-1) . "\n" ;
```

It will display:

```
0:00:00
23:59:59
```

Comment: I understand, @Chiyou. I am confused with these 24 and 12 myself, and for safety I put things the way you do. Anyway, 0:0 is the beginning of the day. If customer wants to run something every Saturday at midnight, you put it at 0 every Sunday.

Comment: A minor point, but to me it makes more sense to run it at 24:00 on Saturday than 0:00 on Sunday. Midnight is more the end of the day than the beginning of the next. Or put another way, it belongs to Saturday night more than it belongs to Sunday morning. 

Of note, we change from Daylight savings time to Standard Time at 2am, partly for this reason. Personally, I think it's more natural for a day to start around sunrise or sundown, but that's me.

Answer (score 20):

**There is no `24:00`**. It's just that PHP *understands* when you input `24:00`, instead of throwing an error, or returning `false` (like before 5.3). If you tell PHP `24:00 today`, it will understand `00:00 tomorrow`. And they're both the same moment in PHP's time representation.

You can *tell* PHP it's `24:00`, but when you *ask* PHP, it will always say `00:00`. `24:00` is just another way of saying `00:00` the following day. There is no zero-length extra second (or something) between `23:59` and `00:00`.

So, I don't understand when you say you can't schedule something for every Saturday at midnight, while you actually have two ways to schedule that: `Fri 24:00` or `Sat 00:00`. No reason for using `Sat 00:01`.

Comment: To me, this is the correct answer. ..although it's technically wrong - hahaha. As far as the technical difference, this explains it as asked, but there is a bit of a typo: `strtotime('24:00 today')` is `0:00` whereas `strtotime('24:00')` and `strtotime('today 24:00')` are `0:00 tomorrow` as I'd expect. Anyway, the concept being that PHP treats `24:00` like I would expect it to treat `37:00` - by wrapping into tomorrow. (PHP doesn't do anything larger than 24:59:59.9̅) though.)

Comment: I didn't mean those literally, as inputs to `strtotime`, but thanks for pointing out what happens if you use them like that.

Answer (score 15):

The notation 24:00 mainly serves to refer to the exact end of a day in a time interval. The last minute of the day begins at 23:59 in the 24 hour time

[From Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock)

> 24:00 = midnight
>   (end of day)
>   shown as start
>   of next day
>   
>   00:00 = midnight
>   (start of day)

But really `24:00 = 00:00` ... no difference but due to compatibility issue i would recommend you use `00:00`

Comment: @Chiyou: PHP 5.3 is the current old stable version of PHP, versions lower than that don't have support. And please remove the social problem from your question, as this is a programming Q&A and less for asking how to deal with pesky clients.

Comment: @Chiyou `24:00 = 00:00` but when you use `24:00` its assumed that your calculation starts `end of day` while 00:00 = `start of day` it does not remove the fact that 24:00 is displayed as 00:00 or vicevasa

Comment: @Chiyou: One general rule if you have problems with clients is to understand them first. If you have a problem to follow what they mean, deal with it in a flexible way, get in the know what they mean so you can express in code what they ask for.

Comment: Its says 24:00 is end of day but shown ad 00:00 .. there is no timer that would display 24:00 and 00:00 at the same time it either from 23:59 to 00:00 or 24.00 the next time would be 00:01

Comment: @Chiyou ... I did not down vote you .. i like your question just gave you upvote instead .. its does not really matter again .. you already have accepted answer ..

Answer (score 3):

24:00 is a valid time and it is not *quite* the same as 00:00 - its a full 24 hours ahead of 00:00

00:00 on the 25th December is the start of Christmas Day.

24:00 on the 25th December is the END of Christmas Day. You could say that it is 00:00 on Boxing Day.

A Boxing Day Sale might start at 00:00 on Boxing Day - and it might end at 24:00 on Boxing Day. Far more convenient than saying 23:59:59.

Answer (score 2):

Just try it yourself (which you should have done with your question so the relation to PHP becomes more clear):

```
echo '00:00 - ', date('r', strtotime('00:00')), 
   "\n24:00 - ", date('r', strtotime('24:00'));
```

Gives the following output ([Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/TlQXuS)):

```
00:00 - Thu, 25 Oct 2012 00:00:00 +0000
24:00 - Fri, 26 Oct 2012 00:00:00 +0000
```

Next thing you could have done (and @Baba pointed to it already) is to just check some resources first like (as a very first step) Wikipedia.

Comment: @Chiyou: More intelligent questions get more intelligent answers normally. Also this was in addition to existing answers I just wanted to point out that you could have clarified your question with some little code. So it's like giving -1 to your own somehow.

Comment: @Chiyou: Correct? Incorrect? I don't know what you try to judge here, but I have the feeling that there is not only confusion at the client side but also on your side. Your job is to understand how the date functions work so you can use them to make your application work. Clarify with your client what "today 24:00" or "monday 24:00" *does* mean. This must not match what it is for `strtotime`. And while you clarify these points, take care that midnight is the start of the day, not the end (commonly). So Saturday Midnight is not Sunday 00:00 but Saturday 00:00 (if you use the 24-hour clock).

Comment: @Chiyou: I can understand that your client is putting you in a stressful situation. But as long as your client isn't from the military I would handle that more civil. Also larger parts of the military even deal differently with that, like preventing 24:00 and 00:00 fully. These two are just not allowed then, so you need to decide for either 23:59 or 00:01. I only said you need to understand what your client wants, but instead you're searching for arguments to backup your position which is shortsighted. Be part of the solution, not of the problem.

Comment: 24:00 is midnight of the next day. 00:00 is midnight of the current day. That's the difference. PHP 5.3's `strtotime` supports 24:00 notation for input. In `date` output, no such thing as 24:00 exists. Sounds good?

Answer (score 2):

The concept of 00:00 / 24:00 is a familiar one to me working in China - in my situation I have dealt with it in terms the coverage period of insurance policies:

An annual policy with an effective date of 01/OCT/2013 24:00 would give coverage from 1st October  2013 to 30th September 2014.

An annual policy with an effective date of 01/OCT/2013 00:00 would give coverage from 2nd October  2013 to 1st October 2014.

Answer (score 2):

Let's convert 24 hour time to 12 hour time. If it's 11:59 PM, in 1 minute it would be 12:00 AM. AM refers to the beginning of the day, and PM refers to the end of the day. If you use 24:00, you would be referring to the end of the day (PM), and 12:00 PM is not at night. So use 00:00.

Comment: Good explanation, but you should add that there is no 24:00. After 23:59 it's 00:00 and that's it.

Comment: The problem with AM/PM is that it's not 100% clear. is 12 noon AM or PM or both? Ask 100 people and I bet you'll get half saying one and half saying the other.

Comment: Simply resolved. Be like the French and don't use A.M. or P.M. - they use **either** "5 heures de l'apres midi" (5 o'clock after midday - lit. "of the after noon") or dix-sept heures (or 17:00 hours).

Comment: I know this is a late comment to another late comment, but I had to add that since PM stands for post meridiem which is "after noon", 5 PM is the same as "5 heures de l'apres midi".  That still doesn't address the statement from @Armstrongest because noon would technically not be AM (ante meridiem) - before noon or PM - after noon.  Traditionally though, 12:00 PM is used for noon and 12:00 AM is used for midnight.